# Is it possible to aggregate Loki logs by day on Grafana?

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana, grafana-loki

I have a set of logs like this:

```
{"action": "action_a", "username": "user_1", "ts": "2021-09-10T02:18:14.103Z"}
{"action": "action_a", "username": "user_2", "ts": "2021-09-10T02:17:14.103Z"}
{"action": "action_a", "username": "user_1", "ts": "2021-09-09T02:16:14.103Z"}
{"action": "action_a", "username": "user_1", "ts": "2021-09-08T02:15:14.103Z"}
```

Is it possible to group the logs by date and username to get a count of unique users *per day*?

I currently have the following query:

```
sum by (username) (count_over_time({job="my-app"} | json | username != "" [$__range]))
```

This effectively gives me a pie chart of unique users for the current dashboard range. Instead, I would like a time-series to show the number of unique users per day (for the past 60 days, for example). In other words, the Daily Active Users (DAU).

With the above logs, I need something like:

```
{"2021-09-10": 2}
{"2021-09-09": 1}
{"2021-09-08": 1}
```

Is this possible with Loki or should I look to something like Elasticsearch instead?

Answer (score 2):

To aggregate by day with LogQL, you can replace `$__range` with your desired time grouping interval.

E.g.

```
sum by (username) (
  count_over_time(
    {job="my-app"} | json | username != ""
  [1d]) # <-- put your desired time interval here instead of $__range
)
```

You can then use a time series visualization to show you your data:

[image: a Grafana dashboard showing user signup per day. It uses the Time Series visualization]

**Useful links:**

- [supported time intervals](https://pkg.go.dev/time#ParseDuration)
- [LogQL metric queries documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/logql/metric_queries/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe creating a new label using label_format would do the trick?
[Labels format expression](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/logql/log_queries/#labels-format-expression)

```
sum by (day) (
  count_over_time({job="my-app"} | json | label_format day=`{{.ts| substr 0 10}}` | username != ""[$__range])
)
```