# sum of count_over_time by day

Tags: prometheus, grafana, grafana-loki

I have the following Loki query in Grafana:

```
sum(count_over_time({filename="/var/log/cron.log", instance="node01"} |= `ERROR` [$__interval]))
```

which gives

[image: results in Grafana]

but I am at a loss trying to group the sum by day.

I tried various versions of `sum by (grouping) (expr)` but that usually ended in parsing errors. The docs don't seem very "all-encompassing".

**I want a table that shows total sum or errors per day (in the given window).**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to aggregate Loki logs by day on Grafana?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69126628/is-it-possible-to-aggregate-loki-logs-by-day-on-grafana)

Answer (score -1):

https://grafana.slack.com/archives/CEPJRLQNL/p1673848218723049?thread_ts=1673553975.491289&cid=CEPJRLQNL

You only need to select type: instance in the grafana logql edit box and your problem should be solved.